# Grabbing String from Embedded MongoID in JSON Java Android

Tags: java, android, json, mongodb

I am working on grabbing information from a JSON.  The server responds with:

```
{
    "id" : {
        "$id" : "515a4f1d03cfebb61800097b"
    },
    "body" : "This is the body"
}
```

I can grab `body` by

```
String body = json.getString("body");
```

But do not know how to get the String contained in 'id'.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do not know how to get the String contained in 'id'.

because current JSONObject contains 1 JSONObject and one body key. to get `$id` from inner JSONObject you can get it as:

```
JSONObject jsonobj_id=json.getJSONObject("id");

// now get $id from id JSONObject

String str_id=jsonobj_id.optString("$id");
```